# can not access nginx docker container

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, docker

apache is installed on host machine.

nginx docker container is created with -p 8080:80 -p 4433:443

```
# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                         NAMES
dcd5ede93662        peratik/nginx       "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   26 minutes ago      Up 6 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4433->443/tcp   nginx

#netstat -tlpn
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      79008/httpd         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      79008/httpd         
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      78854/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::4433                 :::*                    LISTEN      78868/docker-proxy
```

nginx is running:

```
# docker exec -it nginx nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

# docker exec -it nginx service nginx status
[ ok ] nginx is running.
```

Problems:

1. Inside container I can not access port 80:
2. From outside (internet) also I can not open `http://[ip]:8080`

`# docker exec -it nginx curl http://localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`

Please advice
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is something wrong with ipv4 vs ipv6 socket binding.

docker port forwards reports ipv4 addr while netstat output reports only ipv4 addr.